# How to write "If file type is NOT txt or csv, do X" inside for loop?

Tags: python

I have a directory that contains three file types (text, csv, and subdirectories). I have written a version of a script that I want to apply to text files, and an amended version that I want to apply to csv files inside a for loop. Subsequently, I want to ignore subdirectories along with any other file types I might have.

I know I can do something like the following...

```
for file in glob.glob('*'):
    if file.endswith ('.txt'):
        # run script1 here
    elif file.endswith ('.csv'):
        # run script2 here
    else:
        continue
```

But as the script is quite long, I would like to invert the 'else' statement as an 'if not' statement at the beginning of the script - if only to improve readability. I know I can do this with one of the file types (.txt in this case).....

```
for file in glob.glob('*'):
    if not file.endswith ('.txt'):
        continue
    else:
        # run script1 here
```

But how can I alter the script so that I am asking "If file is **not** txt or csv do X, if file **is** txt do Y, and if file **is** csv to Z". I suspect it is a simple fix but I cannot work it out. Here is a previous attempt I have made that generates an error...

```
for file in glob.glob('*'):
    if not file.endswith ('.txt') or ('.csv'):
        continue
    elif file.endswith ('.txt'):
        # run script1 here
    else:
        # run script2 here
```

Comment: just omit the `else` clause in your first example?

Comment: `if not file.endswith('.txt') or file.endswith('.csv')`

Comment: Note, `file.endswith ('.txt') or ('.csv')` *will always be true*. Python isn't english, even if it sometimes comes close, the interpreter sees this as `(file.endswith('txt')) or ('csv')` and `'csv'` is always true, i.e. `bool('csv')`

Comment: Or in short: `if not file.endswith(('.txt', '.csv'))`

Comment: The new version isn't any shorter, and I personally don't think it's more readable.  You will end up writing every possible extension twice instead of just once.  If you want to improve readability, you should instead consider pulling "script1" and "script2" into functions.

Comment: Given that you have to make the check anyway, I think your first example is the clearest. Put the `continue` first only if the rest of the code is the same whether the file name ends with `.txt` or `.csv`, without having to check again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Each boolean expression is evaluated separately.**

`not file.endswith ('.txt') or ('.csv')` evaluated true: not empty tuple considered truthy value.

```py
for file in glob.glob('*'):
    if not file.endswith ('.txt') or not file.endswith ('.csv'):
        continue
    elif file.endswith ('.txt'):
        # run script1 here
    else:
        # run script2 here
```

Answer (score 2):

`or` combines two expressions; it's not *part* of a single Boolean expression.

```
if not (file.endswith('.txt') or file.endswith('.csv')):
```

However, `endswith` itself can take a tuple of strings:

```
if not file.endswith(('.txt', '.csv')):
```

Answer (score 1):

In your third code snippet, you'll have to call the `.endswith()` fumction again, like this:

```
for file in glob.glob('*'):
    if not file.endswith ('.txt') or file.endswith('.csv'):
        continue
    elif file.endswith ('.txt'):
        # run script1 here
    else:
        # run script2 here
```

This should work

Answer (score 1):

Since you are globbing for files anyway, why not only `glob` the files you actually want?

Then you can write much more concisely:

```
from glob import glob

for file in glob("*.txt") + glob("*.csv"):
    if file.endswith(".txt"):
        print("run script 1")
    else:
        print("run script 2")
```

Or even better than that (IMO):

```
from glob import glob

for file in glob("*.txt"):
    print("run script 1")

for file in glob("*.csv"):
    print("run script 2")
```

Answer (score 0):

As the filename has either '.txt' or '.csv', I think, you will get the result you want by using only if statement and you don need `else:continue` clause because if the filename does not have any of these, if condition will fail and nothing arise.

```
for file in glob.glob('*'):
    if file.endwith('.txt'):
        #do something
    if file.endwith('.csv'):
        #do something
```